# In a listview, how can we change the specific item layout of particular position?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

In a listview, how can we change the specific item layout of particular position ?

Comment: You can find the best way to do this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row) and a tutorial [here](https://edisonthk.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/constraints-of-multiple-layouts-listview-for-android/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will create 2 xml files with layout : item.xml special_item.xml . 
In your adapter in get view check if (position=x ) inflate special_item else inflate item .